# How do I index the array to start as 1 rather than 0?

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

In this case the program is supposed to add all the arrays together. However if I entered 1 in the sum method parameter it would start counting from 7 onwards but if I put 0 it outputs 0.

```
public class sList {

   public static void main(String[]args) {
       int[] array = {10,7,11,5,13,8}; // How do I make it read the value 10 as 1 in the array?
       sum(array.length,array);
   }

   public static int sum(int n, int[] S) {
       int i;
       int result;

       result = 0;
       for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
           result = result + S[i];

       System.out.println(result);
       return result;
   }    
}
```

Comment: `for(i=0;i<=n-1;i++) ..`

Comment: I'm going to guess you didn't only change 1 to 0, but you also changed something else, which caused the result to be 0. Otherwise changing 1 to 0 would produce the correct result (except that you would also need to change `n` to `n-1` or `<=` to `<`, but that wouldn't result in 0, but an IndexOutOfBoundsException).

Comment: Best option is remove the array length form arguments.

Comment: `for(i=1;i<=S.length;i++){
 result = result + S[i-1];
}`

Answer (score 8):

I wouldn't pass the length in, because:

- it's redundant - `array.length` tells you the length if you want to know it
- you don't need to know the length anyway, because there's a better way to iterate over an array

Instead, just iterate through the whole array passed in using a [foreach loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html):

```
public static int sum(int[] array) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i : array)
        result += i;
    return result;
}
```

Doing this results in a lot less code, which in turn is easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Array indexes Start with `zero`,The only way i think of is by decrementing the value of i while getting the value.

```
int[] s = {10,7,11,5,13,8}; 

for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    result = result + S[i-1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the array you should change the for-loop:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
```

But if you don't want to do that, you could always make the first element 0:

```
int[] array = {0, 10,7,11,5,13,8};
```

Comment: *"But if you don't want to do that, you could always.."*  ..do something unnecessary and wasteful.

Comment: Change the condition to `i<n` or `i<=n-1`, please.

Comment: @RohitJain How could this raise an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: @11684.. `i <= n` condition will lead to the access of `array[n]`. Now you see.

Comment: @Andrew Totally agree .If you want the sum, change the for loop. Why to start the array with 0.

Comment: @RohitJain I didn't see that, I assume it was a normal for-loop apart from ther `int i= 0;` part

Comment: @vikiiii We don't know the context of the OP's problem, perhaps he's not allowed to change the for-loop because it is homework or some kind of exercise, so I said `you SHOULD change the for-loop...` which should suggest that that is the best option.

Comment: Thank you very much....first time on stackoverflow !! Great Feedback and help guys !!

Comment: @user1883386 then welcome to SO! But could you accept an answer (click the checkmark to the left of an answer) to mark this question as solved and give the answerer his/her earned reputation?

Answer (score 0):

just think about, what it counts on 0 (otherwise on 1):

case 0: (n = length = 6)
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

case 1: (n = 6)
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

literally filled positions in array:
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

in either case, element 6 is not in array so there is an error. in case 1 you "forget" to count the first element with index 0.

thats why you have to write:
for (i = 0; i <= n-1; i++)

Answer (score 0):

Just go ahead and set the for loop at a plus 1 value so that the 0 array value accurately reflects the relative index!

```
for (int i = 0; i < helloArray.length; i++) {

            if (i == max) {
                System.out.println(helloArray[i]);
                System.out.println("=");
                System.out.println(i+1);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Main {

   public static void main(String[]args) {
       int[] array = {10,7,11,5,13,8}; 
       sum(array.length,array);
   }

   public static int sum(int n, int[] S) {
       int i;
       int result;

       result = 0;
       for(i=1;i<n;i+=2)//try changing the value of i++ to i+=2
           result = result + S[i];
           

        System.out.println(result);
         return result;
   }    
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as to how your code works and how/why you think it is better than the other answers, some of which were posted over 10 years ago.